# Overriding DataGridRow style for CodedUI testing produces undesirable appearance

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid, styles, coded-ui-tests

Due to some shortcomings with CodedUI, it's difficult to select items in the DataGrid. One work around that I've found is to override the ItemContainerStyle like so:

```
<DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
     <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">

        <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.AutomationId">
           <Setter.Value>
              <MultiBinding StringFormat="ArisingID_{0}">
                <Binding Path="(DataGridRow.Tag)" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=Self}" />
              </MultiBinding>
           </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>

        <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.Name">
           <Setter.Value>
              <MultiBinding StringFormat="ArisingID_{0}">
                 <Binding Path="(DataGridRow.Tag)" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=Self}" />
              </MultiBinding>
           </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>

     </Style>
</DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
```

and then populate each Row.Tag with a unique ID in the code behind:

```
  private void MyDataGrid_OnLoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = e.Row.Item as IMyViewModel;
        e.Row.Tag = item.UniqueSeqId;
    }
```

However, one issue is that this overrides some of the "default style" of the data grid row - each cell on the data grid seems to be separately selectable, rather than it behaving as just one row.

What's the best way to incorporate the default styles along with these modifications?

Answer (score 0):

There is a `BasedOn` [property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.basedon%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that will set your style, and then add the extra setters you've added:

```
<DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}" BasedOn="{StaticResource DataGridRowStyle}">

    <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.AutomationId">
       <Setter.Value>
          <MultiBinding StringFormat="ArisingID_{0}">
            <Binding Path="(DataGridRow.Tag)" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=Self}" />
          </MultiBinding>
       </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

    <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.Name">
       <Setter.Value>
          <MultiBinding StringFormat="ArisingID_{0}">
             <Binding Path="(DataGridRow.Tag)" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=Self}" />
          </MultiBinding>
       </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

 </Style>
```

Comment: Surely I'd need to define a 'DataGridRowStyle' somewhere though? I don't really follow where that comes from?

Comment: I was under the assumption you had a style, but lost it as soon as you added those setters in your example. But you actually lose default behavior?

Comment: I lose default behaviour, yeah. I do have a default style defined, but it doesn't have an x:Key (So all other DataGridRows default to that style). 

If I add the x:Key and the BasedOn it works for my current DataGrid, but all of the other ones don't!